# `UPDATE.APP` file in Huawei firmwares

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, device-firmware

I found an `UPDATE.APP` file inside of TRT-LX2 firmware ZIP (ROM), but I want to know what does the file do? What does it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huawei OTA updates are traditionally slow for various reasons. However, Huawei let's users manually update their firmware manually and this is where `update.App` comes in. It has the `boot` and `system` image files.

User downloads the latest firmware from Huawei website, extracts this `update.App` and flashes it to update the firmware to the latest. See this [blog](https://www.droidguides.com/extract-install-update-app-file-huawei-firmware/) for the steps. This process may vary for your device and it's best to check on XDA forums to be sure.

Broadly speaking this is the  purpose of the `update.App`, though the process seems to have become more complicated over the years (I owned a Honor 6 phone about 4 years ago)